# Has anyone successfully authenticated with Jmeter against a Windows ADFS/SSO using SPNEGO (Negotiate) and Kerberos?

Tags: jmeter, kerberos

Alternatively, has anyone determined that this cannot be done or does not work?

I am trying to use Jmeter to load test a site that uses OKTA Oauth2 for authorization, but uses ADFS/SSO for authentication. It appears that the authentication scheme is SPNEGO with KERBEROS, which should be supported by the HttpClient. I have no trouble with the OKTA part, but cannot get Jmeter to authenticate against the SSO server.

I have an HTTP Cookie Manager as well as an HTTP Header Manager that has some common Request Header values. I use a separate HTTP Header Manager with HTTP Request samplers when additional Request Header values are required. There is no problem constructing Request Headers (with one exception noted in step 6 below) and cookies are all handled correctly. I am using the default HttpClient4 implementation for the HTTP Request sampler. I am only using an HTTP Authorization Manager where indicated below. Our security team has provided a user and password, and associated keytab, as well as the realm, domain, KDC and Admin servers. krb5.conf and jaas.conf are configured and their location specified. I am not getting any Java exceptions.

```
Jmeter log extract:
            DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy: Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, CredSSP, Digest, Basic]
        DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy: Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
        DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy: Challenge for CredSSP authentication scheme not available
        DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy: Challenge for Digest authentication scheme
```

The problem is that Jmeter does not respond to any of the challenges from the server to carry out the multi-step authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem assuming correct configuration. The same rule as for normal load testing applies: JMeter must send the same network traffic pattern as real browser does. You can double check it using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Double check you set the following [Kerberos-related JMeter properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#kerberos) in *user.properties* file:

```
kerberos.spnego.delegate_cred=true
kerberos.spnego.strip_port=false
kerberos_jaas_application=name_of_your_application_from_the_jaas_conf
```

And just in case add the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
sun.security.krb5.debug=true
```

References:

- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)
- [Java: Kerberos Troubleshooting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I had those settings, but it is good to have confirmation so I can eliminate them as a source of the problem. Similarly, the Kerberos troubleshooting article will be useful in eliminating other potential problems. Unfortunately, the Blazemeter article only deals with the explicit provision of username and password not the SPNEGO approach that is "Negotiated".

Comment: I forgot to ask about Wireshark. I understand what it is, but have never used it. I did do a few captures with Fiddler. Is there additional benefit to using Wireshark vs Fiddler?

Comment: Fiddler can capture only HTTP/HTTPS traffic while Wireshark supports way more protocols. The most interesting feature for you is decryption of Kerberos traffic.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.